# passing a filtered from list value to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I want to put a value from list to df column with condition depending on another column. I tried this but it throws `ValueError`:

```
terms = [0.02, 0.08, 0.24, 0.5, 1, 2]
df['col_1'] = max(list(filter(lambda x: x < df['col_2'], terms)))
```

`col_1` must contain closest to `col_2` value which is less than it. For `0.35` I want to put `0.24`.

How can I achieve that without loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `merge_asof`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_2':[0.35]})

pd.merge_asof(df,pd.DataFrame({'col_1':terms}),
              left_on='col_2',
              right_on='col_1')
```

Output:

```
   col_2  col_1
0   0.35   0.24
```

Comment: You solve a lot of questions using `merge_asof`. I wonder what's the thought process behind it. It's just genius. +1.